# Why wont jQuery Validate work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have ran through the docs and can't figure out where I'm going wrong. jQuery Validate wont work at all. In Chrome dev tools I have no errors or anything, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My view follows this format:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "eventForm" })) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EventName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EventName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", name="eventName", id="eventName" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EventName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
 }

<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#eventForm').validate({
        rules: {
            eventName: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            eventName: "Event name is required"
        }
    });
</script>
```

I added `name` and `id` to all of my elements in the view that I want validated.
Where could I be going wrong? I have no errors or anything like that so I'm not entirely sure? Do I need to include another `<script>`?

Comment: _I added name and id to all of my elements in the view that I want validated_ The HtmlHelpers already do that! And why are you not just adding the `[Required]` attribute to the property and using `jquery.validate,unobtrusive.js` so all this is handled out of the box.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I was trying to play around with jQuery Validation so I didn't necessarily want to do it the easy way with just adding the attribute and calling it quits. Thanks for the information about the HtmlHelpers though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to trigger such as things in page load... like so...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#eventForm').validate({
        rules: {
            eventName: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            eventName: "Event name is required"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I forgot to add - I had tried that yesterday and it still isn't working. However it leads me down a different path. Now my error is:  `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function` in reference to this: `$('#eventForm').validate({` I think I can work with this now since there are good posts on SO about this already. Thanks

Comment: I see that you are serving scripts at "~/scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" but validator at "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" so here is capital "S" maybe that cause not found problem, because it seems validate.js not loaded by this error.

Comment: Good catch - I changed the capitalization there and still getting the same error. It doesn't make sense because I am loading jQuery first and *then* validate... hmmm

Comment: I moved the `<script>`'s to the `<head>` and it's still giving that same error.

Comment: Update: I was adding the jQuery script twice, one in the layout and one in the view. It didnt fix it but it got rid of the error where it wasn't recognizing `validate`.

Comment: Is there a page that we can see problem live ? maybe that helps us to understand situation better..

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to show the problem live.

Comment: ok, is there any error in chrome dev tools "network" or "console panel" ?

Comment: Chech this jsBin out. It is working for me flawlessly: https://jsbin.com/suhaxeg/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @wilsotobianco Thanks for that. It appears that there must be an issue with my out-of-box bootstrap styles. I got rid of them and suddenly it decided to work. Thanks for the help everyone